# Processes hang on read

Tags: c, linux, unix, process, ipc

The following code reads messages from other processes through a pipe. All processes correctly print out all the messages, but then they will never proceed past the while loop. Tried debugging in Eclipse, after reading reading all the messages, it will just stop at that while loop.

The index is a number assigned to each process. The first process would have index == 0.
The message itself is simply the index of the process sending the message.

```
while((n = read(fd[index][0], &mymsg, sizeof(int))) == sizeof(int))
        printf("process%d  has received a message from process%d\n", index, mymsg);
```

Any ideas why this would happen?

Here is how each process writes to another:

```
// Write to other process
if(write(fd[index2][1], &index, sizeof(int)) != sizeof(int))
    sys_error(2);
```

This is done five times. fd is a table of read-and-write ends for each process.

Comment: It's not clear why this isn't precisely the behavior you'd expect. Under what conditions is the code supposed to proceed past the `while` loop?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz If it reads in no bytes or an error is returned.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you would expect either of those things to happen? If not, then why should it exit the while loop? (Is the file descriptor non-blocking?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Each process send 5 messages through a pipe to a randomly selected process. I've posted the code where the write occurs.

Comment: Again, is there any particular reason you would expect it to either read no bytes or return an error? I've yet to hear any reason it should exit the `while` loop. Your code seems to be doing exactly what it is coded to do, keep reading from the connection until an error. No error occurs, so it keeps reading. (How does it know another process isn't about to send it a message?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I guess that means the real question is, how do I let my process know that it's not about to get another message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The call to `read()` is blocking until more data shows up.  From the [man page for pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe)

> If a process attempts to read from an empty pipe, then read(2) will
>   block until data is available. If a process attempts to write to a
>   full pipe (see below), then write(2) blocks until sufficient data has
>   been read from the pipe to allow the write to complete. Nonblocking
>   I/O is possible by using the fcntl(2) F_SETFL operation to enable the
>   O_NONBLOCK open file status flag.

After you open each file descriptor before you enter that while loop do this to each one:

```
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
```

However, you really should read up on blocking vs. non-blocking I/O, including reading the man pages for pipe, read, fcntl, etc.

Comment: Could I have some example code? I'm not too familiar with that function.

Comment: @seljuq70: Did you try the fctntl man page? I just typed 'fcntl F_SETFL O_NONBLOCK' into Google and got a few hits with sample code. In any case I edited my answer to add some more information.

Comment: I tried this before the read: fcntl(fd[index][0], F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK); For some reason process 0 doesn't print anything anymore?

Comment: When you switch to non-blocking I/O you have to keep checking for data. Switching to non-blocking I/O will affect input as well as output. You REALLY need to read up on non-blocking I/O before proceeding. It's not a super-complicated subject, but it's more than should be explained over comments

Comment: Tried that. Processes no longer hang, but one of them is exiting early.

Comment: We've tackled your initial question. One last thing: I'm not explicitly saying you should go to non-blocking I/O. You could also rework your code to deal with blocking read now that you know that read is doing what it's supposed to do. That may be easier for you.

Comment: I think I now understand what's going on. By not using blocking I/O a process will immediately leave the while loop if nothing has been written there yet. Since process 0 gets to the while loop first before the others write to it, it will never see these reads. Now the question lies in how to let the process know when read should stop blocking.

Comment: @seljuq70 How do *you* know when the process should stop blocking? Is it after it receives a fixed number of messages? Is it after a certain amount of time passes? Is it after it receives a message with a particular value? Decide what it should do and then code it to do that. But it sounds like you have no idea how it's supposed to know, so it's not surprising that it doesn't.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It doesn't know how many messages it will receive. All I want each process to do is print out all the messages it will ever receive. That's the issue, it doesn't know how many it will receive.

Comment: @seljuq70 Well that's exactly what it's doing. But, of course, that process never completes since it has no way to know whether or not it will receive any more messages. Your design gives the process no possible way to gather this information. You'll have to decide *how* the process will know, and then you'll have to write code to implement that. But right now, it is doing what you claim you want. (It could receive another message next week. So it is waiting for that.)

Comment: @kbyrd Thanks for answering my question. BTW, it turned out I didn't close the ends of the pipes correctly.